# Deploy a windows service in azure kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, windows-services

I want to deploy a windows service in azure cluster. I have created the yaml file, which deploys the service, however when I run `kubectr get pods` I get the following,

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
windowsservice-deploy-5994764596-jfghj   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          39m
```

My yaml file looks as follows,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: windowsservice-deploy
  labels:
    app: windowsservice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: windowsservice
      labels:
        app: windowsservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: windowsservice
        image: windowskube.azurecr.io/windowsimage:v1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: windowsservice


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: windows-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: windowsservice
  ports:
    - port: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Here is the output kubectl describe pod windowsservice-deploy-5994764596-jfghj

```
Name:           windowsservice-deploy-5994764596-jfghj
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           aks-nodepool1-41533414-vmss000000/10.240.0.4
Start Time:     Mon, 15 Jun 2020 11:24:18 +0100
Labels:         app=windowsservice
                pod-template-hash=5994764596
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             10.244.0.8
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/windowsservice-deploy-5994764596
Containers:
  workerservice:
    Container ID:
    Image:          windowskube.azurecr.io/windowsimage:v1
    Image ID:
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-zvwh8 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-zvwh8:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-zvwh8
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                    From                                        Message
  ----     ------   ----                   ----                                        -------
  Warning  Failed   18m (x330 over 93m)    kubelet, aks-nodepool1-41533414-vmss000000  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff  3m11s (x395 over 93m)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-41533414-vmss000000  Back-off pulling image "windowskube.azurecr.io/windowsimage:v1"
```

It's a windows service and I haven't deployed on before, am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: share output of kubectl describe pod windowsservice-deploy-5994764596-jfghj  and kubectl get events

Comment: are you using azure AKS or it's a kubernetes cluster cluster that you have deployed on azure? What is the version of kubernetes?

Comment: Thanks I have shared the output above

Comment: Is this specific problem with windows service or linux images also getting same error ?Have you followed any docs?

Comment: this is an issue a get with windows service only, for webapi or weapps works fine

Comment: I wonder whether is the  ports:  - port: 80  type: LoadBalancer that causes the problem with windows services

Comment: Have you succeeded with running Windows service in Kubernetes? Or did you converted it to console application?

Answer (score 2):

Given `windowskube.azurecr.io/windowsimage:v1` seems to be your private Azure container registry, I think the missing piece is to provide kubernetes with the login credentials to the private registry.

See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

As has been mentioned, by doing `kubectl describe pod windowsservice-deploy-5994764596-jfghj` and scrolling down to the bottom to view the `Events`, you'll get a better error message describing why the image pull has failed.

Comment: Thanks I have shared the output above

Answer (score 2):

By default, an AKS cluster is created with a node pool that can run Linux containers. Use `az aks nodepool` add command to add an additional node pool that can run Windows Server containers alongside the Linux node pool.

```
az aks nodepool add \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --cluster-name myAKSCluster \
    --os-type Windows \
    --name npwin \
    --node-count 1 \
    --kubernetes-version 1.16.9
```

Follow this full guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-container-cli)